# Как поменять цвет Tabs из библиотеки garden React JS?

Tags: reactjs, tabs

Здраствуйте, на моем сайте есть синие табсы из библиотеки garden(https://garden.zendesk.com/components/tabs#tabpanel). Как я могу поменять их цвет допустим на черный (по умолчанию стоит синий) ? Пробовал поменять с помощью className и style
JSX:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Tabs, TabList, Tab, TabPanel } from '@zendeskgarden/react-tabs';
import './fd.css'

const Garden = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('tab-1');

  return (
    <Tabs selectedItem={selectedTab} onChange={setSelectedTab}>
      <TabList className="tabs-element">
        <Tab item="tab-1">Elm</Tab>
        <Tab item="tab-2">Sugar Maple</Tab>
        <Tab item="tab-3">Dogwood</Tab>
      </TabList>
      <TabPanel item="tab-1">
        Elms are deciduous and semi-deciduous trees comprising the flowering plant genus Ulmus in
        the plant family Ulmaceae.
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel item="tab-2">
        The sugar maple is one of America’s most-loved trees. In fact, more states have claimed it
        as their state tree than any other single species—for New York, West Virginia, Wisconsin,
        and Vermont, the maple tree stands alone.
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel item="tab-3">
        Cornus is a genus of about 30–60 species of woody plants in the family Cornaceae, commonly
        known as dogwoods, which can generally be distinguished by their blossoms, berries, and
        distinctive bark.
      </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Garden;
```

CSS:

```
.tabs-element {
    color: black
}
```

Comment: Следует указать пример кода с описанной проблемой, в идеале чтобы другие еще смогли запустить и воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @Slavik я добавил пример кода, с помощью className я создал класс и в отдельном файле CSS прописал изменение цвета, но он не работает

Comment: Сейчас у меня нет времени запускать код и смотреть самому, могу лишь порекомендовать то, что делал бы я: открыть dev tools, смотреть появился ли класс в html, в нужном ли он месте и если так, то дальше инспектировать (также в dev tools смотреть) его стили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно в этом случае проблема в том, что стили из библиотеки перекрывают заданный стиль для класса `tabs-elements`

В css в таких случаях можно использовать свойство [!important](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp), которое дает наивысший приоритет прописанному стилю:

```
.tabs-element {
   color: red !important;
}
```

*Стоит предупредить, что использование `!important` должно быть крайней и нежелательной мерой. В данном случае, когда необходимо перекрыть стиль библиотеки, это еще допустимо, но в своем коде, когда можно переписать селектор или добавить классов элементу в html прибегать к использованию `!important` не стоит вообще.*

*Также рекомендую к освоению [dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) в браузерах.*

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог